# Jsch error - failed to send channel request

Tags: sftp, jsch, channel

I  am trying to connect to a SFTP remote server using JSCH library version 0.1.49. Every time I run the program I receive the following error :

```java
Initializing...
Connection to SFTP server is successfully
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Unable to connect to SFTP server.com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
at shell.MainClass.JschConnect(MainClass.java:95)
at shell.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:30)
```

line 30 is : `sftpChannel.connect()` from the code below :

```java
    System.out.println("Initializing...");
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    Session session = null;
    try {   
        session = jsch.getSession(ProjectConstants.rmUsername,ProjectConstants.rmHost, 22);
        session.setPassword(ProjectConstants.rmPassword);

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();
        if (session.isConnected() == true) {
            System.out.println("Connection to SFTP server is successfully");
        }

        ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
        try {
            sftpChannel.connect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JSchException("Unable to connect to SFTP server. "
                    + e.toString());
        }
```

the credentials I am using are correct ( it connects through FileZilla using the same data ), and I also disabled the proxy for that server ( either way I get the same error with or without proxy )

If anyone could help me I would greatly appreciate it as I am stuck with this error for about a week now ...

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you have `sftp` installed and running on the machine you are trying to connect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if SFTP server is started and running.

I had encountered the same issue - I was not able to open SFTP channel to my server, but I could connect with WinSCP. It took me some time to notice that WinSCP would fallback to SCP hence confusing me. Starting the server solved this issue.

Comment: It seems their server has some problems ( not sure which ... ), even though they assured me the first time that everything is all right and the problem is on my side on theirs. Still waiting for them to fix their problem , Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Check `Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Answer (score 1):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I changed:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

to:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

It helps.

Comment: I use PhpStorm in Mac and get this error when adding deployment server via SFPT. I've done like you said but is not work