# Java program to copy files from Linux remote server to windows local machine

Tags: java, linux, windows, jsch

I am trying to make a java program that copies file from a given directory in remote linux server to my windows machine.
I have made the following program:

```
  package abc;

import com.jcraft.jsch.Channel;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class Copy 
{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
        String hostname = "10.0.0.100";
        String username = "pratz";
        String password = "pratz";
        String copyFrom = ".";
        String copyTo = "."; 
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        System.out.println("Trying to connect.....");
        try {

            session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect(); 
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel; 
            sftpChannel.get(copyFrom, copyTo);
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done !!");



    }

}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: failed to send channel request
Done !!

at com.jcraft.jsch.Request.write(Request.java:65)
at com.jcraft.jsch.RequestSftp.request(RequestSftp.java:47)
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:237)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
at abc.Copy.main(Copy.java:34)
```

When I tried copying files using WINSCP,the files get easily copied from remote linux server to windows machine.How to make my java program to copy files from linux to windows?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769164/jsch-error-failed-to-send-channel-request

Comment: Try to use scp instead of sftp

Comment: when i replaced sftp with scp in my code,it throws this exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at abc.Copy.main(Copy.java:34)
at Channel.connect()

Comment: Is there any other way to write such program?...i can't  start the server....i don't have admin rights for that server